# Error while upgrading from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4

Tags: magento2

After typing below in CLI I ran composer update.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 --no-update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/zendframework/zend-barcode%24ddcc1cb490598ed29ea4ff3bb37037db35d582ff2b08a096bef4c88dd8e572e5.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.5 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.4 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.3 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.2 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.1 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.10.5 requires php ^5.6 || >=7.0 <7.3 -> your PHP version (7.3.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer ~2.10.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v2.10.1, v2.10.2, v2.10.3, v2.10.4, v2.10.5].
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 --no-update --no-dev
```